# Assignment needs exactly one word on the left hand side

Tags: qt, qml

I was trying to centralize a variable from .pro file into my project by trying to define it and print in another .qml file

.pro file

```
VERSION=2.4
DEFINE APPVERSION=VERSION;
```

.qml file

```
text: qsTr(APPVERSION)
```

this seems to give me the above subjective error. Must there be any other way.

Answer (score 0):

DEFINE works for C++, it is not for qml so a possible solution is to convert the DEFINE to string and then export it to qml using setContextProperty:

***.pro**

```
VERSION = 2.4
DEFINES += APPVERSION=$$VERSION
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
// ...

#define QUOTE_(x) #x
#define QUOTE(x) QUOTE_(x)

// ...

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("APPVERSION", QUOTE(APPVERSION));

// ...
```

*.qml

```
text: APPVERSION
```

Comment: Oh wow It worked ! Thank you so much ......I never know coding community was so helpful :D

Comment: @SHREERAKSHABHAT Please review the [tour]